# Test SameSite and Secure cookies in Django Test client response

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework, samesite

I have a Django 3.1.7 API.
Until now I was adding `SameSite` and `Secure` cookies in the responses through a custom middleware before Django 3.1, depending on the user agent, with automated tests.
Now that Django 3.1 can add those cookie keys itself, I removed the custom middleware and still want to test the presence of `SameSite` and `Secure` cookies in the responses.

So I added the following constants in settings.py, [as Django doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE):

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

But when I look at the content of the responses in my tests, I don't get any `SameSite` neither `Secure` cookie keys anymore. I printed the content of the cookies, and it's not there.

**Why?**

Here are my tests:

```
agent_string = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"
from django.test import Client
test_client = Client()
res = test_client.get("/", HTTP_USER_AGENT=agent_string)
print(res.cookies.items())
```

I also tried with the DRF test client just in case, with same result:

```
agent_string = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
test_client = APIClient()
res = test_client.get("/", HTTP_USER_AGENT=agent_string)
print(res.cookies.items())
```